# transpose row content into one column and then do the same for the next row

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` called `full_data_string_split_removed2`. When I do this `SP <- which(full_data_string_split_removed2$split1 == "SP#")` then I get the row number where it finds the the expression `SP#`.
Doing `print(full_data_string_split_removed2)`gives: [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fp15wqa7AvUnByY05pWEhRTDZSbWRfSC1VOTh0YTNGdEx3/view?usp=sharing)

Doing: `Number_of_SP_lines <- length(SP)` and `print(Number_of_SP_lines)` gives `[1] 425` in this case which is correct.
First of all the constant is that I have a line where the the expression `SP#` can be found in column `split1` and the second constant is that it is followed by 103 rows of data as can be seen in my example data. However the number of `SP#` occurences for different datasets can be different.
So what I need to achieve is:

1. Grep the entry in column `split7` in the row where it finds `SP#` in column `split1` and divide that value by `60` and copy into a new table cell A2 where A1 would have the name of column `sample` and `repetition` from the row where it fullfills the criteria of `SP#` in column `split1`.
2. Then transpose the entries in columns `split2` to `split11` for the following 103 rows into the new dataframe/table under the entry of bullet point 1 and these are 1024 entries.
3. Do step 1 and 2 for the remaining `SP#` occurrences whereas each `SP#` occurence should get its own column.

Comment: Can you add a better description of the expected output? I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what you want to do. Is the expected output one dataframe? Several? In the example where there are 425 occurrences of `SP#`, what would be the dimensions of the expected dataframe(s)?

Comment: `@duckmayr` in this case I expect one dataframe/table with 425 columns (SP#) occurrences and 1026 rows. the first row would be the samplename+repetition, second row would be thevalue divided by 60 and row 3 to 1026 would be the transposed values. However, in another case I could only have 400 SP# occurrences and therefore would only need one dataframe with 400 columns and 1026 rows.

Comment: I think the number of rows should actually be 1032:
1 for samplename+repetition,
1 for the value in split7 divided by 60,
and 1030 for 103 rows * 10 columns for split2-split11

Comment: `@duckmayr`. It works really well apart from it is only displaying the value from column `split7 divided by 60` for the first 25 occurrences of `SP#` and all the other 400 are displayed as `NA`. I don't see what the problem could be. And I used the first attempt where it strictly has to be 103 rows. another point just for completeness sake the 103rd row is only filled for columns `split2 to split5`, but that does not make any difference to what I want.

Comment: That's because there are 400 rows where `split1` is `SP#` and `split7` is `NA`; `NA / 60` is equal to `NA`. You can confirm this with the command `sum(is.na(tbl1$split7) & grepl('SP#', tbl1$split1))` (the output will be 400)

Comment: `@duckmayr` I see. I just doublechecked and for the first 25 cases the value is in column `split7` and the rest is in `split6` Could there be a test  implemented which cell in that particular row is filled and when it finds a value divides that by 60?

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do what you want:

```
# Read in the data
tbl1 <- read.csv('SP21_only.csv')
# Find the rows where SP# is in split1
SP_indices <- which(grepl('SP#', tbl1$split1))
# Then store in tbl2, for each SP_indices row
tbl2 <- sapply(SP_indices, function(i){
    # That observation of sample + that observation of repetition
    c(paste(tbl1$sample[i], tbl1$repetition[i]),
      # That observation of split7 / 60
      tbl1$split7[i] / 60,
      # And concatenation into a vector the transposition of the next
      # 103 rows for the columns split2-split11
      c(t(tbl1[i + 1:103, paste0('split', 2:11)])))
})
```

Note the dimensions of the resulting matrix will be 1032 rows and 425 columns as explained in my comment above. This will work for any number of `SP#` occurrences, but it only works if there are always 103 rows between `SP#` occurrences. If you need it to work for an arbitrary number of intervening rows, you can do the following:

```
# Read in the data
tbl1 <- read.csv('SP21_only.csv')
# It will be convenient to go ahead and paste together sample and repitition
sample_repetition <- paste(tbl1$sample, tbl1$repetition)
# Then we get a vector of length nrow(tbl1)
# that increments in value everytime split1 contains SP#
# This groups or separates the data into segments we need
groups <- cumsum(grepl('SP#', tbl1$split1))
# Then store in tbl2, for each group
tbl2 <- sapply(1:max(groups), function(x){
    group_indices <- which(groups == x)
    first_index <- min(group_indices)
    # The relevant element of sample_repetition,
    # The relevant element of split7 / 60, and
    return(c(sample_repetition[first_index], tbl1$split7[first_index] / 60,
             # the concatenation of the transposition of the relevant submatrix
             c(t(tbl1[group_indices[-1], paste0('split', 2:11)]))))
})
```